# PayPal REST API: Get Subclass, e.g. Sale, from PayPalModel Superclass

Tags: php, rest, symfony, paypal

I am trying to use the PayPal REST API within my Symfony 2 web app. Currently I am working on handling an `WebhookEvent`, a callback my page receives from the PayPal API.

Beside other the `WebhookEvent` offers the two methodes `getResourceType()` and `getResource()`. Depending on the concrete type of the Event the deliverd Resource is different. Thus `getResourceType()` return a String indicating what kind of resource is included and `getResource()` will return the resource itself.

**The Problem:** No matter what `getResourceType()` is used, `getResource()` always returns an object of type `PayPal\Common\PayPalModel`, which is the superclass of all the different resource classes. So even if `getResourceType()` is `sale`, an `PayPal\Common\PayPalModel` object is returned and not a `\PayPal\Api\Sale` object:

```
...
$webhookEvent = \PayPal\Api\WebhookEvent::validateAndGetReceivedEvent($request->getContent(), $this->getApiContext());

$resource_type = $webhookEvent->getResourceType();
//  ==> 'sale'

$sale = $webhookEvent->getResource();
//  get_class($sale) ==> 'PayPal\Common\PayPalModel'
```

Since an `PayPal\Common\PayPalModel` is returned I cannot use any of the methods the subclass `\PayPal\Api\Sale` introduces:

```
$id = $sale->getParentPayment();
//   ==> Fatal Error: Call to undefined method PayPal\Common\PayPalModel::getParentPayment()
```

**So what can I do, to work with the deliverd resouce as `\PayPal\Api\Sale` and use all its methods?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the returned ResourceType equals "sale", then you can create the sale Object like this:

```
use PayPal\Api\Sale;
$eventResource = $webhookEvent->getResource();
$sale = new Sale($eventResource->toJSON());
echo "PAY-ID: ".$sale->getParentPayment();
```